# Pass storyboard outlet to base controller class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

I have a base class:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    var posts = [Post]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? PostTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PostTableViewCell.")
        }

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.parentViewController = self
        cell.initialize(post: post)

        return cell
    }
}
```

That I use as a subclass:

```
class FeedViewController: BaseViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // Other stuff
}
```

I use the base class to handle all table view functions (which I reuse in many parts of my app).

In my storyboard, I have a controller design set up for `FeedViewController`, with a table view. However, I'm not sure how to pass my storyboard outlet, which is currently connected to `FeedViewController` to my base controller, so that the base controller handles all the table view logic. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't instantiate `BaseViewController` in code directly, then just move outlet declaration in base class (storyboard will handle this automatically)

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // Other stuff
}

class FeedViewController: BaseViewController {

    // Other stuff
}
```

Comment: What if I subclass BaseViewController in many other view controllers, and have a separate storyboard and table view for each?

Comment: it is not static, every subclass will have own tableview connection to own instance in storyboard, base class has only declaration.